Backpacking stove adapter
I will be hiking a long-distance trail where they don't have screw-on gas cartridges compatible with my stove but only Campingaz easy-click ones. Has anyone used a converter or adapter? There are almost none in my country. I don't want to buy a new stove just for one part. I am thinking about ordering one from abroad, and I don't know if they are safe or even used often.
Update 1:
There are some adapters available on the internet, but is like hit and miss, very unclear. I decided the safest best is use puncture style one - Balkans are Balkans. If is the puncture style safe for hiking I really don't know. One old one at home has a holder box, to hold the cartridge in place. I think if check for smell - leaks before every usage, like I do with screw one and have it on top of backpack it should be reasonably safe.

Where are you going?

I see a variety by Googling, but don’t know if any of them are correct (or safe).

are you sure screw-on cartridges are not available?

It is the Balkans, man.

I did use one some time ago (this model for reference : https://en.monrechaud.com/kovea-pat-adapter.html) it did work very well with no leak or performance issues and is easy to use.
To be safe I only connected the cartridge at use time, never during storage, the cartridge self seal when disconnected.
I consider a good piece of kit as it let me use any available cartridge (where I live easy click and screew on are both available but most store stock only one or the other...)

I have the same one and agree with your evaluation. I find it a bit clunky, though (as an extra piece of equipment), and it impacts stability a bit if you use it with a burner that is screwed on the top of the cartridge.
